# How to transpose column to rows with sql DB2

Tags: sql, transpose, db2-400

I have the following table1:

```
ITEM1|ITEM2
COOKIE|CHAIR
PIE|TABLE
PIE APPLE|PENCIL
BANANA CAKE|PEN
```

expected output results:

```
ITEM_ALL
COOKIE
PIE
PIE APPLE
BANANA CAKE
CHAIR
TABLE
PENCIL
PEN
```

Can someone help with the query, for transpose column to rows? Thank you before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select item1 as item_all from table1
union all
select item2 as item from table1;
```

If you want to remove duplicates, then use `union`  rather than `union all`.